# SearchFilter functionality from data fetched from wp backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm working on category filters and also trying to implement search function. To search for items.
My category works perfectly, but still finds it hard to implement the search filter for items.
My items are fetched from wordpress backend.

My SearchFilter component:

```
interface IEventSearchFilterProps {
  eventData: Record<string, any>;
}

const EventSearchFilter: React.FC<IEventSearchFilterProps> = ({
  eventData,
}) => {
const handleSearch = () => { 
    
  };

return (
    <StyledEventSearch>
      <Container>
        <Form>
          <Row>
            <Col xl={5} lg={5} md={6} sm={12}>
              <InputGroup>
                <AppInput
                  onChange={handleSearch}
                  placeholder={'Search for event'}
                  icon={<AiOutlineSearch />}
                />
              </InputGroup>
            </Col>
           </Form>
           </Container>
}

my event data is totally from the backend.
```

Comment: If there is an option to send query parameters to the WP backend try that first.

Comment: If you receive all the data at once you can filter the received data using javascript .map / .filter methods. Also, you can check out https://fusejs.io/ to search your data object more efficiently.